Would absurd redundancy be merely an error in style, or something more like a cut and dry grammatical error
I am writing an essay discussing the language wars. For illustrative purposes, I mention that absurd redundancy is an error, but unsure if that is "just" a stylistic error or a usage or grammar error that is far less subjective.
Examples I came up with include (they are absurd, but that’s the point)
Feline cat
Wooden lumber
Golden gold
Wet water
Canine dog
Etc.
These strike me as more than just a style problem, but I am not sure why.  Are such errors just problems in style, or are they something more egregious? They strike me as being something like a conjugation error or other black and white grammatical error, but, again,  I am not sure why.
My question is in terms of prescriptive grammar, although I suppose something like this would go against generative grammar and the hard wired language "flashware" in our brains.

Well, My Big Fat Greek Wedding is redundant for the laugh, and the whole film plays up the same pushing it to the limit and beyond.

Not everything that's wrong with language use is a grammatical error. These are (probably) pleonasms. I suggest you read up on grammar/syntax and other linguistic terminology. It's hard to know what kind of question this is or what kind of answer you want. It looks like you just want someone to agree with you, which would make this an opinion-based question or a rant. But maybe you want a historical analysis of what academics, pedants, or other celebrity commentators have said about pleonasm, or I don't know what else? What "language wars" are these?

Wet water does exist for the purposes of fire-fighting and wooden lumber can be a useful term in some contexts, like when differentiating it from plastic imitations.
Prescriptivist grammar is mostly style advice, and there will always be counter-examples possible where following the advice would produce non-idiomatic or inconvenient results. That said, few would recommend avoiding anything that looks like tautology as a hard rule.

The use of tautology in your writing can give the impression that you
are careless in your choice of vocabulary.   On the other hand,
tautology can be used with intention, adding emphasis, clarity, and an
occasional twist. ( Teri Lapping  —  Grammar Tips)

For example, for emphasis or to draw attention to its color, golden gold seems perfectly acceptable.

It grew upon me like a fungus, as I looked at the case, and nothing
else would catch my eye, that I must have that locket, -- it was such
a beauty, such beaten, burnished, golden gold; such chasing and
enamelling, such a charming initial in tiny diamonds, which was the
very thing. (The Atlantic)

Grammar being generally concerned with syntax (adjectives are allowed as pre-head modifiers in noun phrases, etc.) and not semantics, the sort of redundancy you have identified would not fall into a clearly defined grammatical error, and would best be considered from the viewpoint of style.
